# How to change the structure of a table if a variable is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm selecting a table from a stored procedure which returns different columns if one of my variables is null vs. when it isn't.  How do I declare a table differently based on one of my inputs?  The code below communicates what I'm trying to do, but I get an error that I'm declaring the table twice if I try to do it this way.

```
IF @Input IS NOT NULL BEGIN
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE (
    Var1 FLOAT,
    Var2 DATETIME,
    VAR3 INt,
    ...
)
END
ELSE
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE(
    Var1 INT,
    Var2 FLOAT,
    Var3 DATETIME,
    ...
)
```

Comment: This isn't possible. Variable declarations happen as though hoisted to the beginning of the batch not at the point of the `DECLARE` so you can't declare them twice. Probably easiest solution is just to declare two different tables variables.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, 2 tables, then use a variable with your IF statement to point to the correct table from there on out.

Comment: How about using `select into` to create the table from what is returned by the SP?

Comment: @τεκ - That will still not be allowed. `IF 1=1 SELECT 1 AS C INTO #T ELSE SELECT 2 AS C INTO #T END` gives `There is already an object named '#T' in the database.`

Comment: OK. Here's a related question with some possible answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two different table variables ... @stage  ,  @stage1 .

Answer (score 2):

This is the only way I can think of to do what you're after, and it isn't friendly. You need to jump scope to declare the same variable table:

```
DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(5),@TableFields VARCHAR(1000)
SET @Input = NULL
BEGIN
IF @Input IS NOT NULL 
 SET @TableFields = 'Var1 FLOAT,Var2 DATETIME,VAR3 INt' 
ELSE     
 SET @TableFields = 'Var1 INT,Var2 FLOAT,Var3 DATETIME'
EXEC ('DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE ('+@TableFields+')
      INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (''1'','''','''')
      SELECT * FROM @tbl

    ') 
END
```

Easier to use 2 table variables and point to each based on your IF logic, imo.